# How would you punctuate a separate sentence within parentheses with an ellipsis at the end?

Tags: ellipses, parentheses

For context:

> I think the whipped cream really helps cut through the strong alcohol taste, and >it also adds some fat, so give it a shot! (No pun intended…)

Do I need to put a period/full stop after the closing parenthesis? I tried this and feel it looks a bit off, but I'm not sure how else to change this sentence around.

Comment: You need four dots instead of three ... three form the ellipsis and one is the period for ending the sentence, although I don't think you distinguish them in any way.... [See this online style guide.](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html)

Comment: I don't get what is missing in the 'elipsis'. Nor do I get the pun. Maybe I'm slow, today.

Comment: The pun is about the alcohol in the recipe. I guess my question is whether "(No pun intended...)" can be left “floating” like that without a period at the end. "(No pun intended...)." looks weird to me